# Jetty Runner IDEA Community Logging

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty

I am working on a project using Intellij IDEA Community, so I am using Jetty Runner to deploy my web application in localhost, everything is working ok, but I want to configure logs regarding Jetty, at server startup I see  this kind of log :

`14:50:20.516 [main] DEBUG o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - isSystemResource==false org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpDec jar:file:/C:/Mario/development/spring/spring5/workspace/springsecurity/chapter02/chapter02.00-calendar/build/exploded/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/expression/spel/ast/OpDec.class
14:50:20.516 [main] DEBUG o.e.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader - WAP webapp loaded class org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpDec
14:50:20.516 [main] DEBUG o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - isSystemResource==false org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OperatorNot jar:file:/C:/Mario/development/spring/spring5/workspace/springsecurity/chapter02/chapter02.00-calendar/build/exploded/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/expression/spel/ast/OperatorNot.class
14:50:20.517 [main] DEBUG o.e.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader - WAP webapp loaded class org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OperatorNot
1`

I want to change the granularity from DEBUG to info regarding jetty server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `jetty-logging.properties` file in your resources folder and configure the logging there:

```
# Configure for System.err output
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
# Configure StdErrLog to log all jetty namespace at default of WARN or above
org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=INFO
```

More info here: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-logging.html